# Bulk Move ASP.NET Pages Into A New Namespace?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, namespaces

I have an C# ASP.NET Web Application Project where all the pages are in the global/default/top-level namespace. (I have no explicit namespace declarations. And when I look at my compiled web application's DLL in Red Gate's .NET Reflector, I can verify that all the classes are in the top-level .NET namespace.) Is there any good, automated way to move all the pages and custom controls into a new namespace, say "MyWebApplication"? Ideally it'd be nice to do it with just Visual Studio, but I'd be open to considering a commercial refactoring tool if necessary.

I thought maybe by setting the "Default namespace" property in the project's Application properties I could get the compiler to implicitly put all pages into the specified namespace, but this appears not to be the case; this "Default namespace" setting seems to make Visual Studio insert *explicit* namespace declarations into *new* pages, rather than implicitly affecting the namespace of any existing pages.

If it matters, my immediate motivation here is to try to run a static analysis tool (CAT.NET) on my web application; the tool seems to have a quirk or two with code in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Chris it may look silly as you are ready to pay for the refactoring tool to do it. But consider this:

The namespace is declared in the code-behind file by default as the project/application name. So if you project name is MyWeb the default namespace will be

```
namespace MyWeb
{

   public partical class MyWebPage....
```

Now this is refered in ASPX page as follows:

```
 <%Page ... CodeBehind="MyWebPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWeb.MyWebPage"
```

You only need to change these two things to put into effect the namespace migration. And frankly this can be achieved using **Find/Replace** dialog. Please make a copy of your complete solution and try it!!

Cheers

Comment: I think he's saying that none of his pages have a namespace, which is what Visual Studio does by default for a Website Project. Find/Replace won't work because there are no namespaces defined.

Comment: Yup, Nathan got it right. This is no longer a pressing problem for me, but I guess there's still no answer SO folks have come up with yet.